# Show that $\phi$ is nowhere differentiable in $\mathbb R$ if $\alpha \beta >1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

> Let $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and $F$ be the extension of $f$ on the entire real line defined inductively as $:$
>
> $$F(x)=f(x+2).$$
>
> Let $\phi_n(x)={\alpha}^nF({\beta}^n x)$ for some $0 < \alpha <1$. Prove that $\sum \phi_n$ is uniformly convergent in $\mathbb R$ to a continuous function $\phi$. Further, if $\alpha \beta >1$, then show that $\phi$ is nowhere differentiable in $\mathbb R$.

Would anybody please make it clear to me that how $F$ is defined here in an inductive way? I dont clearly understand the defination of $F$. If it is well understood I think I can proceed. Please help me in understanding it first. Then let me try it for a while. If any problem will occur then I will ask for further clarification.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $F$ is basically the periodic function with period 2 such that on $[2k-1,2k+1]$, $F(x)=|x-2k|$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is inductive because evaluating $F$ of some number reduces to finding it for another value. Repeating this will end in finitely many steps, thus defining it for all real numbers.

Perhaps this is best seen through an example. How will you evaluate $F(-10.5)$? Well, $$F(-10.5)=F(-8.5)=F(-6.5)=F(-4.5)=F(-2.5)=F(-0.5)=\lvert -0.5\rvert=0.5$$

Comment: Yes that's the point. Why does $F(x+2)=F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$? Would you make it clear to me?

Comment: I believe that may have been a typo. They probably meant $F(x+2)=F(x)$ for all $x$, and $F(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in[-1,1]$

Comment: Oh! Then it's fine. But the question is quite confusing. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I figured it was a typo because otherwise $F(x)$ is only defined over $[-3,-1]$

Comment: Right. That was my confusion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I find difficulty in proving the nowhere differentiable part. I have tried to do like Rudin's approach. But there is a problem here. Here there may exist no $m$ such that for all $n > m$, ${\beta}^n \delta_m$ is an even integer. How can I avoid such thing?

Comment: It's getting late where I am. I will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know why they didn't just say "periodic extension". That's what this is.

Comment: Could you explain what Rudin's approach is? How is $\delta_m$ defined?